# Bash export variables received lines by lines

Tags: bash

I got a simple problem but very boring.

The goal is to write a shell script that run on EC2 instance to exports tags for rest of the script... Something like:

```
ec2-describe-tags [...]
    | while IFS=':' read name value; do
        export "$name"="$value"
    done
```

Not so uggly but don't work, of course cause the export is in the while loop, executed in pipe.

My question is: how to write this correctly? Of course I cannot predict names nor numbers of received tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that the output consists solely of lines of the form `name:value`, you should just be able to do

```
while read; do
    export "$REPLY"   # Using default variable set by read
done < <( ec2-describe-tags ... | sed 's/:/=' )
```

You could even get fancy with the `readarray` command (if available) and simply run

```
readarray -t env_vars < <(ec2-describe-tags ... | sed 's/:/=')
export "${env_vars[@]}"
```

The process substitution allows the `while` loop to run in the current shell, so the exported variables will be put in the shell's environment.

If you are using `bash` 4.2 or later, you can set the `lastpipe` option, which allows the last command in a pipe to run in the current shell instead of a subshell, allowing you to keep your current pipeline.

Comment: `IFS=:` implies that the output consists of `name:value`, not `name=value`.

Comment: Ok, so if I can `sed` like `while ... done << (ec2-describe-tag | sed) `  ?

Comment: You can use `sed` like that, but depending on what you are doing, it may be unnecessary. I'll fix the `=`-vs-`:` issue pointed out by Barmar; I read the question too quickly.

Comment: Unless you are thinking of using `... | sed 's/:/='`, which would be quite nice. It would salvage the too-clever `readarray` solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
while IFS=: read name value; do
    export $name="$value"
done < <(ec2-describe-instance ...)
```

A pipeline runs the commands in a subshell, so the variables don't persist when it's done.